# Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему выдаёт unreachable statement и что нужно исправить?

Tags: java

public class MaxMethod {

```
public static int max(int[] values) { throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    int max = values [0];
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++)
        if (values[i] > max)
            max = values[i];

    return max;
}
```

int max = values [0] - здесь выдаёт эту ошибку

Comment: Это сообщение выдается, если какой-то участок кода никогда не будет выполнен и до него невозможно добраться. В общем-то после `throw new UnsupportedOperationException();` ничего выполнено и не будет т.к. будет исключение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Неправильно скобки стоят. Из-за чего у вас при выполнении метода сразу выбросится исключение, (при любых условиях), и код дальше выполняться не будет. Исправленный код ниже:

```
public static int max(int[] values) throws UnsupportedOperationException {

    int max = values [0];
    for (int i = 1; i < values.length; i++)
        if (values[i] > max)
            max = values[i];

    return max;
}
```

Comment: и какая же операция в коде ниже может привести к UnsupportedOperationException?

Comment: никакая. То автору вопрос, зачем ему это исключение.